# Extract blocks/structures using div/span styles from html via beautifulsoup/python

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup, structure

I understand how to obtain the text from a specific div or span style. But now I need to build up blocks/structure from these information.

For example, my html contains titles with: `style = 'font-family: BBCDEE+Arial-BoldMT; font-size:13px'; contains contents with: style = 'font-family: CBCDEE+ArialMT; font-size:12px'.`

Now I intend to not only extract all the titles and contents, but also make blocks/structure from that, i.e. get a list of blocks:

```
Block 1: title1 content1 content2

Block 2: title2 content3

Block 3: title3 content4 content5 content6

...etc.
```

which means generate a structure with all the data in the original sequence, separating by different types of span styles.

Comment: Can you give some example data and desired output for that data?

Comment: @BlackJack https://www.pwc.com/sg/en/illustrative-annual-report-2005/assets/62-71.pdf use this as an example. If I treat text in red as titles and treat text in black as content, and I got the span styles of them. I would like to have some blocks like (see page 66): Block 1: title 1(Directors in office at the date of report), content 1(if a director was...); Block 2: title 2(Directors' interests in shares...), content 2 (Directors' interests include...), content 3 (Interests in rights or share options....), content 4(If a ....)........ Block3 etc.